# Linear fractional transformation and ellipses.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, conic-sections, mobius-transformation

Let $C$ be an ellpse on the complex plane. Then by the linear fractional transformation $\tau \colon z \mapsto -1/z$ what is the image of $C$?

It is well-known that when $C$ a circle, $\tau(C)$ is also a circle including a line, i.e., its radius being infinite. I wonder what is the case when $C$ being an ellpse. I think in the typical case of $C \colon x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ with $z = x + iy$, where $z$ is the variable of the complex plane ${\Bbb C}$, its image $\tau(C)$ should be an ellipse. I am checking it.

I would like to know what if $C$ being located in the general position on ${\Bbb C}$.

Comment: Do you know the transformation called "inversion", characterized by $z \to 1/\bar{z}$ (i.e., the combination of your transformation and conjugation, which amounts geometrically to a symmetry wrt $x$-axis) ? Now have a look for example [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/cpM7tQiR) in order to see that the resulting curve can vary a lot even in this particular case where the origin is taken in one of the foci).

Comment: Sorry, but I am still at a loss what is the result of my question with your suggestions. Do you mean that the image of ellipse by the linear fractional transformation becomes still an ellipse?

Comment: No, on the contrary, the image is in general a closed curve (with very variable shapes) which is never an ellipse.

Comment: Jean, great thanks! By the way, could you give me a couple of concrete examples of the linear fractional transformations maybe shocking which might convert an ellipse into a very strange shape?

Comment: You get things like limacons and Cassini ovals. If a curve is defined by the plane equation $P(x,y)=0$, the inverse curve is defined by $P(u,v)=0$ where $(u,v)=(x/r^2,y/r^2)$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2$. If $P$ is a polynomial, denominators may be cleared in $P(u,v)=0$ to make it a polynomial equation in $x$ and $y$ too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in the case of the (black) ellipse whose equation

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$$

is displayed on the top left line with coefficients' values for $a,b,c,d,e,f$ that can be read on the cursors.

Transformation $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ gives as the image of the ellipse the blue curve looking like a bumped circle (it is rather surprizing that the bottom part of this blue curve is almost a perfect circular arc).

[image]

Let us explain how I have obtained it in two steps using Geogebra :

$$\underbrace{z \to Z=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}}_{\text{inversion}} \ \ \text{followed by} \ \   \underbrace{Z \to \bar{Z}}_{\text{symmetry wrt x-axis}}$$

being understood that these two transformations are resp. called (by Geogebra) "reflexion" wrt the unit circle (featured in green) and the $x$-axis.

The important thing one can observe (and that can be rather easily proven) is that the resulting curve is a **quartic** (algebraic curve with degree 4).

Changing the values of coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$ yields a good diversity of curves. Here is another example:

[image]

Comment: Dear Marie, great thanks. Pierre